# Calculate Max score - Min score per supplier in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I'd like to calcualte Max score - Min score for a project in pandas dataframe

current df looks like this:

```
projectID supplierID score
1         1          50
1         2          60 
1         3          75
```

I want it to look like this: 
max-min => 75-50 = 25

```
projectID supplierID score max-min
1         1          50    25
1         2          60    25
1         3          75    25
```

and I want to do this action for each projectID

Comment: what if i want to calculate the difference between each score with the max score? how to achieve that?

Answer (score 4):

Using [`np.ptp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.ptp.html) ("peak to peak"):

```
df['max-min']=df.groupby('projectID').score.transform(np.ptp)
#df.groupby('projectID').score.transform(np.ptp)
Out[229]: 
0    25
1    25
2    25
Name: score, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) to broadcast results back passing a lambda function that subtracts [`max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.max.html) and [`min`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.min.html)

```
df['max-min'] = df.groupby('projectID').score.transform(lambda s: s.max() - s.min())

    projectID   supplierID  score   max-min
0   1           1           50      25
1   1           2           60      25
2   1           3           75      25
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `groupby` to get the max and the min, and then `join` the results on your "projectId" as a new column:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1, 30],
                   [1, 2, 50],
                   [2, 1, 60],
                   [2, 2, 40],
                   [1, 3, 20]],
                  columns=["projectID", "supplierID", "score"])

df.join(  df.groupby(["projectID"])["score"].max() 
        - df.groupby(["projectID"])["score"].min(), 
        on="projectID", rsuffix="_max-min")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GroupBy` + `transform`:

```
g = df.groupby('projectID')['score']
df['max-min'] = g.transform('max') - g.transform('min')
```

The `transform` method aligns results from a regular `GroupBy` to the grouper series.